# How to get DVD menu from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, dvd

When I insert a video DVD in my PC, I get the DVD's menu. How can I do the same from within Windows 7 when the DVD is already in the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `Computer` (through start menu) then right click on the optical drive and choose `Autoplay` or whatever the option is in Bold - This should launch the same program/command as putting the disk in.